# Series involving zeros of Bessel functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, bessel-functions

I am trying to calculate some quantities related to the dynamics of acoustic vibrations in a spherical medium, and I have come across the following series:
$$
S = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{iz_{2,n}\Omega}}{z_{2,n}}.
$$
where the numbers $z_{2,n}$ are the zeros of the spherical Bessel function of order 2 ($j_2(z)$), or equivalently the zeros of the regular Bessel function $J_{5/2}(z)$, excluding $z=0$. $\Omega$ stands for some real parameter.

Noting that for $z$ large enough one can approximate $z_{2,n} \approx (n+1)\pi$, I have been able to approximate
$$
S \approx \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{i\Omega\pi(n+1)}}{\pi(n+1)} = -\frac{e^{i\pi\Omega} +Log\left(1-e^{i\pi\Omega}\right)}{\pi}.
$$
However, I am not very satisfied with this result as I think its accuracy is quite important in my case. Does anyone here know whether the sum $S$ has some exact solution, or how can I get a more accurate result?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A prosaic idea : separate your infinite series into two parts : a first one with say the first ten or fifty terms, and then, on the remaining part (only), applying your approximation...

Comment: Thanks, good idea! I definitely will do that if I cannot come up with an analytical expression, although best for me would be to find such an expression since solving for $S$ is an early step in my derivation and it would be extremely convenient :)